Exercise: Does $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=0$ imply independence?
I want to do the following exercise:$\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}$ $\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}$
We already know that $X,Y$ being independent implies $\Cov(X,Y)=0$. Does $\Cov(X,Y)=0$ imply $X,Y$ are independent? (Give a proof or find a counterexample.)
I don't think that $\Cov(X,Y)=0$ should imply $X,Y$ independent.
I wasn't able to come up with a working counterexample.
But here is what I tried so far:
My first try:
Let $X,Y$ be random variables $\Omega \rightarrow \{-1,1\}$ such that
$\mathbb{P}(X=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$,
$\mathbb{P}(X=1)=\frac{1}{2}$.
Then we can define $Y$ to be:
$Y=1$ if $X=-1$
$Y=-1$ if $X=1$
Thus we get:
$\mathbb{P}(X=-1,Y=-1)=0,\mathbb{P}(X=-1,Y=1)=\frac{1}{2},\mathbb{P}(X=1,Y=-1)=\frac{1}{2},\mathbb{P}(X=1,Y=1)=0$
Then we have $\Cov(X,Y)=\E[(X-\E[X])(Y-\E[Y])]=\E[XY]$.
The problem was that $\E[XY]=(-1)\cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2}+1\cdot (-1) \cdot \frac{1}{2}=-1$.
Thus I couldn't use this as a counterexample.
Second try:
Define $X$ such that:
$\mathbb{P}(X=-1)=\frac{1}{3}$,
$\mathbb{P}(X=0)=\frac{1}{3}$,
$\mathbb{P}(X=1)=\frac{1}{3}$.
Let $Y:=X^2$.
Then $XY=X^3$, where we know that
$\mathbb{P}(X^3=-1)=\frac{1}{3}$,
$\mathbb{P}(X^3=0)=\frac{1}{3}$,
$\mathbb{P}(X^3=1)=\frac{1}{3}$.
We know that $\E[X]=0,\E[X^3]=0$, thus
$\Cov(X,Y)=\E[(X-\E[X])(Y-\E[Y])]=0$.
Now I wanted to show that $X,Y$ are not independent i.e $\E[XY] \neq \E[X]\E[Y]$.
My problem here is that since $\E[XY]=\E[X^3]=0$ and $\E[X]=0$, $X,Y$ are independent. So this example didn't work either.

See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12842/covariance-and-independence

@KurtG. The link you posted is a counterexample. But I was trying to find a "simple" one if possible.

@NTc5 I think you confused one result of independent random variables (i.e. $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$) with the criteria to being independent. Lets consider your first example. To show that $X,Y$ are dependent you have to show that $\exists x,y$ s.t. $P(X=x,Y=y) \neq P(X=x) P(Y=y)$. Note that since $Y$ can have two possible values $P(Y=1)=P(Y=-1)=1/2$. Now $P(X=-1,Y=1)=1/2$ but $P(X=-1)=P(Y=1)=(1/2)(1/2)=1/4$. Thus $X$ and $Y$ are dependent rv.

The first counterexample linked amounts to choosing $(X,Y)$ at random from ${(-1,0),(-1,0),(1,-1),(1,1)}$ with equal probability for each of the four cases. I don’t think there can be a simpler example than that.

A non-mathematical counterexample for intuition: imagine cycling up the hill that's getting progressively steeper and you wish to move at a constant speed. In order to do this, you need to apply more and more force. In this case, your speed and applied force are uncorrelated (as one is constant and one increasing), while they are certainly not independent.
